# Get array key with value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

my array looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  &array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Key"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "0040"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "key2"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "transport"
  }
}
```

I try to get "transport" but the only value i have is "key2".

i tried it with in_array etc. but all these examples just worked with a $key => $value structure.

I need to use this format of array because the api i calling needs it like this.

Thank you

Comment: Show us what you've tried please. You might be closer to the solution than you expect

Comment: Even if the use of the more fancy array functions still eludes you yet, getting this done by simply _looping over_ the data should be a trivial excercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop and look for a value.

Here the first Bob's age is found.

```
<?php

$people =
[
    ['Bob', '76'],
    ['Allison','52']
];

$result = null;
foreach($people as list($name, $age)) {
    if($name == 'Bob') {
        $result = $age;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
string(2) "76"
```

You can use `array_column` to help build a map, here of names to ages.

```
$name_age = array_column($people, 1, 0);
var_export($name_age);
echo $name_age['Allison'];
```

Output:

```
array (
    'Bob' => '76',
    'Allison' => '52',
)52
```

Or just:

```
echo array_column($people, 1, 0)['Bob'];
```

Output:

```
76
```

A loop will do to construct a map, similar to the $name_age example above:

```
foreach($people as $person) {
    $name_age[$person[0]] = $person[1];
}
```

Note when building a map with array_column or the loop, if you have more than one Bob, values will be overwritten by later occurances.